# Laravel 5 Eloquent: How do I sort db rows and also get rank?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a user and referral table with a one-to-many relationship.  I'm trying to get the rank of a user based on referral count compared to other users. I only got as far as being able to list the users according to their referral count.

```
$users = App\User::with('referrals')->get()->sortBy(function($user)
{return $user->referrals->count();});
```

But I don't know how to get the rank or sort the rows based on referral count.

this is my referral table :

```
    Schema::create('referrals',function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->bigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');  
        $table->bigInteger('referral_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

So for example if I have this in my db

```
user id 1 | 5 referrals
user id 2 | 10 referrals
user id 3 | 1 referral
```

I want to be able to get the rank of user id 2, which is 1.

Comment: Since you already have sorted array, you know that the first user in this array has most referrals. So they will have rank 1. Isn't that simple ? What else do you need ?

Comment: I need the rank # indicating that the user has the most in comparison to other users.  I'm showing this in the users profile.  So like user-> rank = ?  But I don't want to create a rank column.  I want to get the rank of the specific user based on the sort.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$users = App\User::with('referrals')
                  ->get()
                  ->sortBy(function($user) { return $user->referrals->count(); }, SORT_REGULAR, TRUE);
```

But remember this sort is not happening in DB.
Now for ranking,

```
$rank = 0; 
$last_count = -1;
foreach($users as $user){
   if(count($user->referrals) != $last_count){
       $rank++;
       $last_count = count($user->referrals);
       $user->rank = $rank;
   }
   else {
       $user->rank = $rank;
   }
}
```

This code will add the rank to the user. Same referral count will be the same rank.

**Update:**

If you want a specific user's rank then you could do this..

```
$rank = 0; 
$last_count = -1;
foreach($users as $user){
   if(count($user->referrals) != $last_count){
       $rank++;
       $last_count = count($user->referrals);
   }
   if($user->id == $specificUserId){
       break;
   }
}
echo "User's Rank: ".$rank;
```

Comment: I need to get the individual rank of each item.

Comment: Thanks.  But this makes changes to db column every time rank changes.  I just want to be able to get the rank of a specific user based on the sort.

Comment: Actually it will not change anything in db. I just added a new property `rank` with every user object.